# Why can't I assign value on didSet?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have two view. On my first view i create some data and send to other view lets name view2. So my view1 has code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showUserDetail" {
        (segue.destinationViewController as! UserDetailTableViewController).detailContact = detailCoversationContact
    }
}
```

In my `detailCoversationContact` i have detail about this one user, this detail like number, nick etc. Now as i expect this data are put to variable `detailContact` in my view2

And this is my cod in view2 this code is work:

```
class UserDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nickNameLabel: UILabel!

var nickMy: String = ""

var detailContact: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.detailContact {
            self.nickMy = (detail.valueForKey("nickName") as? String)!
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nickNameLabel.text = nickMy      
}

}
```

When i send data to `detailContact`' i check is didSet if yes i set my `nickMy` and this is work. But what is first ? setting my var or viewDidLoad?

this is my code and not working and can someone explain why ?

```
class UserDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nickNameLabel: UILabel!

    var detailContact: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
            if let detail = self.detailContact {
                   self.title = detail.valueForKey("nickName") as? String
                   self.nickNameLabel?.text = (detail.valueForKey("nickName") as? String)!
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Ok this is `self.title` and work i see the name of user but title is from tableView. But my nickNameLabel is not change ? why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of `prepareForSegue`, the `IBOutlet`s have not been set up yet.  So, `self.nickNameLabel` is still `nil`, and *optional chaining* makes `self.nickNameLabel?.text = ...` safely do nothing.

Set the value in `viewDidLoad()` when the `IBOutlet`s have been set up:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.nickNameLabel?.text = (detail.valueForKey("nickName") as? String)!
}
```

Alternatively, you can trigger `didSet` by setting the `detailContact` to itself in `viewDidLoad()`.  You have to trick Swift in order to do this because it thinks assigning `detailContact` to itself does nothing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    detailContact = (detailContact)  // trigger didSet to set up the label
}
```